# C++ std::tr1::hash for a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, hash, unordered

I have this templated class:

```
template <typename T> Thing { ... };
```

and I would like to use it in an unordered_set:

```
template <typename T> class Bozo {
  typedef unordered_set<Thing<T> > things_type;
  things_type things;
  ...
};
```

Now class Thing has everything it needs except a hash function. I would like to make this generic so I try something like:

```
namespace std { namespace tr1 {
  template <typename T> size_t hash<Thing<T> >::operator()(const Thing<T> &t) const { ... }
}}
```

Attempts to compile this with g++ 4.7 have it screaming

> expected initializer before ‘<’

about the

```
hash<Thing<T> >
```

part of the declaration. Any clues will help save the few remaining hairs on my head.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot provide a specialization for just `hash::operator()(const T&)`; just specialize the entire `struct hash`.

```
template<typename T>
struct Thing {};

namespace std { namespace tr1 {
    template<typename T>
    struct hash<Thing<T>>
    {
        size_t operator()( Thing<T> const& )
        {
            return 42;
        }
    };
}}
```

Another way to do this is to create a hasher for `Thing`, and specify this as the second template argument for the `unordered_set`.

```
template<typename T>
struct Thing_hasher
{
  size_t operator()( Thing<T>& const )
  {
    return 42;
  }
};

typedef std::unordered_set<Thing<T>, Thing_hasher<T>> things_type;
```

Comment: I believe this is one of the rare cases where you may write inside the std namespace :-)

Comment: @rwols Yes, you are allowed to add specializations to the `std` namespace

Comment: Sadly for me only the second option will work. It is probably the case that the first will work under C++-11 but my application has to go both ways. The first option produces conflicts with existing definitions of hash<T> pre-C++-11. Many thanks all the same.