# How to implement std::hash for a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a template class looking like this:

```
template <int N, class TypeId> class Indexer {
...
}
```

and I want to use it in `std::unordered_map`, I need a hash function.
In the codebase we already had something similar (but on an untemplated class) so I tried to do it like this:

```
namespace std {
template <int N, class TypeId>
struct hash<Indexer<N, TypeId> > {
    size_t operator()(const Indexer<N, TypeId>& id) const noexcept {
        ...
    }
};
}
```

It is also quite similar to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451198/c-stdtr1hash-for-a-templated-class).
Unfortunately this does not work, just gives a bunch of unhelpfull errors. Any insights?

Comment: "This does not work" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: If the errors were helpful to you, you wouldn't need to ask. But the fact that they're unhelpful to *you* doesn't mean they will be unhelpful to *us*, who you hope to solve the issue. Post the full error messages, along with a [mcve] (the code to reproduce them).

Comment: What is the first line of error message that does not start with "in file included from" or "in instantiation of" or "required from here"?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that partial specialization for `std::hash`, you need to show the actual errors (and the related code)

Comment: Note that a "template class" is rather misleading. You don't have a class (yet). `Indexer` is a "class template", a sort of template to create classes.  The template instantiation `Indexer<5, int>` would be a class.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing a semi-colon at the end of the definition of the Indexer class.

This works:

```
#include <functional>

template <int N, class TypeId> struct Indexer {};

namespace std {
template <int N, class TypeId>
struct hash<Indexer<N, TypeId> > {
   size_t operator()(const Indexer<N, TypeId>& id) const noexcept { return 0; }
};
}

int main() {
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The semi-colon is there. The class is already used somewhere else!

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual Studio 2022, with C++ 14, I also got errors, and neither solution above worked. Omitting the template arguments after "hash" did the trick for me.

```
namespace std {
  template <int N, class TypeId>
  struct hash {
    size_t operator()(const Indexer<N, TypeId>& id) const noexcept { return 0; }
  };
}
```